# Random issues creating new types in Dexterity TTW

Tags: plone

I have just installed dexterity into our office's intranet site so that I can create some new types for particular styles of documents. I had hoped just to use just the TTW capabilities, but I'm seeing extraordinary behaviour. When I try to create the fields of a new type, any, or all of the following problems can be seen, almost non-deterministically:

- After saving the attributes of a new field, the field sometimes doesn't get shown in the page showing the fields of that new type.
- Sometime a page refesh does show it, other times it doesn't.
- Clicking on the Settings for a field (when it is visible) sometimes shows the error dialog indicationg that this page does not exist.
- Sometimes the settings dialog does come up, and then attempts to save it fail with another error dialog to say that this page does not exist.

With a bit of persistance by retrying and refreshing often, I can get a type defined with a couple fields. Then when If I create an instance of this new type, often only some subset of those new fields are shown in the creation form. When I try to save it, the form is shown again but this time with the required fields that were originally hidden now highlighted in red. Finally saving that object then displays it with some fields (but not all) missing.

It's seems utterly random.

I have added the following to my buildout:

```
extends =
    base.cfg
    versions.cfg
    http://good-py.appspot.com/release/dexterity/1.0.3?plone=4.1

...
eggs = 
    ...
    plone.app.dexterity
```

My Plone is:

```
Plone 4111
CMF 2.2.4
Zope 2.13.8
```

The event.log doesn't have any messages in it when these problem are occuring.

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: there are some bugs on the packages pinned on Dexterity KGS 1.0.3; please use the following instead: http://good-py.appspot.com/release/dexterity/1.0.3-1?plone=4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a caching server in front of Plone?  Maybe that is being too agressive and it is caching stale content.  Try accessing Plone directly without any caching servers in between and see if that helps.

Comment: I was just typing in an response when your's came in. It does seem to be due the apache front end, which I have configured to use proxy_balancer. So by going via port 8080 directly to one of the plone instances makes it behave. Thank you.

Comment: Note that having a caching server in between is still a good idea in most circumstances, but here it apparently needs a bit of tweaking.

Comment: Absolutely. I will still keep the load balancer - I haven't got around to putting a caching front-end like varnish yet. I hope that varnish is more powerful to configure for load balancing so that the interaction of clients with dexterity objects is not broken.